# How long does Google take to reindex the website after a complete overhaul?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I've recently launched a couple of websites and am wondering how long it usually takes Google to remove the old pages that now are either redirected or result in 404 errors. It's been about a week since I launched the first one and it seems the old page links are still above the new ones. I've submitted the Sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools just two days ago.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the process?

Comment: I also thought that we would have answered this question before.   I found several related questions, but no exact duplicates:  [How long will Google take to index our site correctly after cleaning up a pharmaceutical hack?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/how-long-will-google-take-to-index-our-site-correctly-after-cleaning-up-a-pharma)

Comment: Also:  [Re-indexing website with clean URL's](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30430/re-indexing-website-with-clean-urls) and [How can I force Google to re-index my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34807/how-can-i-force-google-to-re-index-my-site)

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I think your second link gave me the best answer. I guess the best thing to do is to always make URL redirects and simply submit your Sitemap.xml through Webmaster tools, afterwards there's not much else to do than have patience :-)

Answer (score 2):

This depends wildly on how popular your website is and how many pages need indexing. It's not possible to give a definite number, but it will take many weeks to index a larger site, and even longer when Google isn't really interested in your site.

You can control the crawl rate in [Google Search Console → Settings](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/settings) → Crawl Rate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked out the crawl rate but I think I'll just leave it to the recommended option by Google. I've already submitted new pages to the index, so now they just need to earn their SEO value.